# How to create circle icon from image file?

Tags: c++, qt

In my customized QWidget paintEvent method, I want to draw a circle with a circle shaped image icon. The source image is loaded from file and then automatically casted into circle using QPainter composition. How to do it? Thank you!

```
void DotGraphView::paintNodes(QPainter & painter)
{
    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
    painter.drawEllipse(x, y, 36, 36);
    QPixmap icon("./image.png");
    QImage fixedImage(64, 64, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    QPainter imgPainter(&fixedImage);
    imgPainter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
    imgPainter.drawPixmap(0, 0, 64, 64, icon);
    imgPainter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
    imgPainter.setBrush(Qt::transparent);
    imgPainter.drawEllipse(32, 32, 30, 30);
    imgPainter.end();
    painter.drawPixmap(x, y, 64, 64, QPixmap::fromImage(fixedImage));
}
```

The above code does not work. The output display is not a circle shaped image.

Comment: Please elaborate on how it does not work. Does it compile? Does it run at all? Does it produce output that is wrong? In which way?

Comment: The output display is not a circle shaped image.

Comment: What is it exactly ? Can you upload a screenshot ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but this might do what you want:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QBitmap>
#include <QPainter>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   // Load the source image.
   QPixmap original(QString("/path/here.jpg"));
   if (original.isNull()) {
      qFatal("Failed to load.");
      return -1;
   }

   // Draw the mask.
   QBitmap  mask(original.size());
   QPainter painter(&mask);
   mask.fill(Qt::white);
   painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
   painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(mask.width()/2, mask.height()/2), 100, 100);

   // Draw the final image.
   original.setMask(mask);

   // Show the result on the screen.
   QLabel label;
   label.setPixmap(original);
   label.show();

   return a.exec();
}
```

Cache the result in your QWidget subclass and blit to the screen the required bounding rect in your paint event when requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this relatively simply with a clipping path:

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
painter.drawEllipse(30, 30, 36, 36);
QPixmap icon("./image.png");

QImage fixedImage(64, 64, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
fixedImage.fill(0);  // Make sure you don't have garbage in there

QPainter imgPainter(&fixedImage);
QPainterPath clip;
clip.addEllipse(32, 32, 30, 30);  // this is the shape we want to clip to
imgPainter.setClipPath(clip);
imgPainter.drawPixmap(0, 0, 64, 64, icon);
imgPainter.end();

painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, 64, 64, QPixmap::fromImage(fixedImage));
```

(I'd cache the pixmaps if you do this often.)